# Doom Emacs: where to put org-mode configuration items

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Windows 11
WSL2
Debian
Emacs 27.1
Doom emacs
New install, totally unconfigured at the moment.

Hi, I am a newbie at emacs/doom emacs and am trying to configure org-mode for the first time. What config file do I put my config items in (init.el, config.el, custom.el or other) ?

Following the following tutorial as a starting point for configuring:
https://config.daviwil.com/workflow

Many thanks for any help,Simon

Comment: Maybe you can ask that question on https://emacs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Just in your `config.el` is enough.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31467119)

Comment: He asked where the configuration in the link should go (init.el, config.el, custom.el or package.el, which have a specific meaning in Doom), and I answered `config.el`, which I think I made pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

in config.el (duh) and in `(after! org ... )` block. For example if you want to add capture templates they can only be set after org package loads:

```
(after! org
    (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
            '("T" "Custom todo" entry
                    (file+headline +org-capture-todo-file "Inbox")
                    "* TODO %?\n%i%U\n%a" :prepend t))
    (add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
            '("J" "Custom journal" entry
                    (file+olp+datetree +org-capture-journal-file)
                    "* =%<%H:%M>= %?\n%i\n%a" :kill-buffer t))
```

> I am a newbie at emacs/doom

For whomever reads it in the same situation - may god help you.